# How to refresh table after con.commit() in java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, transactions

I am creating a new register in table MY_TABLE using java and then, I am doing a query to obtain the max(id) of that table. However, Java is obtaining the previous one. I mean:

```
mybean.store(con)
con.commit();
pstm = con.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX (ID) FROM MY_TABLE");
                rs = pstm.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()){
                    id =  rs.getString("ID");
                    System.out.println("id: " +id);
                }
```

Before con.commit(); the table has the max(ID)=3

After com.commit() the table has the max(ID)=4

But I obtain MAX(ID)=3

Can somebody help me to solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `rs.getString(1)`? An `ID` column doesn't exist in that query.

Comment: Following up on @TheImpaler's comment - if you want the column containing the result of the MAX function to be named `ID` then you need provide a name for it in your query: `SELECT MAX (ID) AS ID FROM MY_TABLE` or `SELECT MAX (ID) ID FROM MY_TABLE` will both do it - I prefer the former because it's easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it; if this is returning the wrong result either your DB doesn't contain what you think it contains, or your DB engine is broken (MySQL is often broken, possibly that's the problem. The fix is to not use mysql), or your code is broken. Your snippet contains an error (no semicolon after the first line), so this isn't a straight paste but a modification; generally you should paste precisely the code that is exhibiting the behaviour you don't understand, because if you edit it or try to simplify it without running the simplification, you may have accidentally removed the very thing that would explain what you're observing.

More generally, if all you want is the ID generated for an auto-increment column, this isn't how you do it. You can use statement's `.getGeneratedKeys()` method to get at these; you may have to pass in `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` as part of your `executeUpdate` call.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need a `PreparedStatement` if you do not have a parametrized query. I would use `Statement` in this case.
2. You do not need `while (rs.next())` as your query will return a single value. I would use `if (rs.next())`.
3. Your query does not have a field called `ID` and therefore `rs.getString("ID")` will throw `SQLException`. You should use `rs.getString(1)` or use an alias (e.g. `maxId` in the example shown below) in the query. Also, you should use `getInt` instead of `getString`.

   ```
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxId FROM MY_TABLE");
   int id = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   if (rs.next()) {
       id = rs.getInt(1);  
       //id = rs.getInt("maxId");  
   }
   System.out.println(id);
   ```